# Put a Linearlayout under the ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I'm facing problem to put a linearlayout under the listview like what is shown in this image link:

[image]

I want the layout with the Add icon and text:"Add New Members" to be displayed under the listview. What am I doing wrong? Pls help me to solve the problem. Thank you very much.

This is the xml file for the layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.thomasbrown.myapplication.MemberActivity"
android:background="@android:color/white">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/groupID"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/ListView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/add"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/addMember"
                android:text="Add New Members"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>


<Button
    android:text="Leave this group"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/leaveGroupButton"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: My suggestion is to add it as a footer for the ListView .

Comment: use relative layout as parent of listview

Comment: use button for add new member. it has property to add icon on left

Comment: Ok, I will try to do it. Tq for answering my question.

Comment: If member count is 10 then what will be the layout behavior? do you want to show "Add new member" button always?

Answer (score 1):

Problem is you have `android:layout_weight="1"` on your `ListView` which will make it expand to full and give no space to your `LinearLayout`

Comment: Should put `android:layout_weight="1"` inside linearlayout instead od listview

Comment: Ya. I just noticed that. Tq for reminding me about this.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you want to make `"Add New Members"` button `scrollable` and `relative` to `ListView` height, use `NestedScrollView` as a container of `ListView` and `"Add New Members"` custom button `LinearLayout`.

**Here is full XML code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/groupID"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/ListView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/white" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_add_new_member"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/add"
                    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:id="@+id/addMember"
                    android:text="Add New Members"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <Button
        android:text="Leave this group"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/leaveGroupButton"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

2. If you want to make `"Add New Members"` button fixed at bottom, use `RelativeLayout` as a container of `ListView` and `"Add New Members"` custom button `LinearLayout`.

**Here is full XML code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/groupID"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_add_new_member"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

            <ImageView
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/add"
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:id="@+id/addMember"
                android:text="Add New Members"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/ListView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_above="@id/layout_add_new_member"
            android:background="@android:color/white" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:text="Leave this group"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/leaveGroupButton"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image: OUTPUT:]

Hope this will help~

Answer (score 0):

```
 <ScrollView ..

   <RelativeLayout.. 

      <LinearLayout // vertical orientation

          <ListView ../>

          <LinearLayout  // your linear layout
              layout_below="@+id/listviewid"
      </LinearLayout>

   </RelativeLayout>

 </ScrollView>
```

Try this view hierarchy.

Comment: Never put `ListView` under `ScrollView`

Answer (score 0):

You have to make changes in you list view item for this, check this.

Add below lines into Adapter get view method:

```
    @Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

            view = LayoutInflater.from(TestListActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.dummy, viewGroup,false);

                    LinearLayout layout =  (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.add_bottom_ll);
                    if(i==getCount()-1){
                        layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }else{
                        layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
            return view;

        }
```

List view Item view xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/profile"
                android:layout_width="72dp"
                android:layout_height="72dp"
                android:src="@drawable/arrow" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/profile"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/profile"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="user Name"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/add_bottom_ll"
            android:layout_width="363dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/index" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/addMember"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Add New Members"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

View(Activity or Fragment) xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.thomasbrown.myapplication.MemberActivity"
        android:background="@android:color/white">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/groupID"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/ListView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                />

        </LinearLayout>


        <Button
            android:text="Leave this group"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/leaveGroupButton"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Ok, I will try to do it. Tq for answering my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try RelativeLayout and use android:layout_above as shown below:

```
    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/your_listview"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_above="@+id/your_layout_with_buttons" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:id="@+id/your_layout_with_buttons"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

//your buttons come here

            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tried but you try this and let me know:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:background="@android:color/white">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/groupID"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp" />

<Button
    android:text="Leave this group"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/leaveGroupButton"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/leaveGroupButton"
    android:layout_below="@id/groupID">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/ListView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/ListView1">

        <ImageView
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/add"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/addMember"
            android:text="Add New Members"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: down voting the answer as nested weights are bad for performance.

Comment: Please contribute by answering.

Comment: I tried this coding just now. The linear layout has successfully displayed under the listview. But the leaveGroupButton which should be at the bottom of the layout is missing.

Comment: Edited. But didn't try. Now check. If still not working then I will myself run & see.